# External JavaScript file is unresponsive for form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating an html file that links to an external JavaScript file to validate a form in my html file. Every time I hit "Submit" on my form, the page is simply re-loaded and no JavaScript is performed. I have already tried Chrome and Firefox, plus I have disabled pop-up blocking as well as ensuring JavaScript is enabled.

As far as I can tell so far, my JavaScript file is not being reached, since the first line of the single function in my JavaScript file has a call to `alert()`, and no pop-up or dialog windows are appearing.

My HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files are all uploaded to the same directory, and the html file is successfully linking with the CSS file because my style changes are clearly apparent.

Why won't my JavaScript file be reached?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head lang="en">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" charset="utf-8" />
            <title>TitleLine</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css"/>
            <script type="text/JavaScript" src="checkTheForm.js" >
            </script>
        </head>
           <body>
                <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate()">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Survey</legend>

                            <label>Name: </label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>

                            <input type="submit" />
                            <input type="reset" />
                       </fieldset>
                   </form>
               </body>
     </html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validate()
{
    var myDay = new Date();
    var locMyDay = myDay.toLocaleDateString();

    alert("testing");
    console.log("hi");

    if(document.forms["form1"]["name"].value == "")
    {
        alert("Name field is blank - please enter a name.");
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
        document.getElementById("name").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("name").style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    }

    else
    {
        alert("Form successfully submitted at:  " + locMyDay);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing that you need to do is check the browsers console for errors. Press the F12 key. Locate and click the console tab within the developer tool area then F5 key. Is there any items in red within the console area?

Comment: I don't know how far nativeJS supports it but try looking for `event.preventDefault()` and afterwards `element.submit()` .

Comment: @jeff found this in my JavaScript file: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`..... checking this out now

Comment: @jeff This worked! Thank you for the heads up to check the developer tool area.